# Move build files into distribution files as per folder structure with Gulp

Tags: email, gulp

I'm trying to integrate our gulp workflow for emails into the same website build (website is running on Laravel 5.4 and compiling assets using Laravel Mix - running via npm watch/production on command line) and Emails will be running off a modified version of [Bulletproof Email](https://github.com/koomai/bulletproof-email) (have combined it with the sass build of foundation emails to include the panini template builder) on gulp (using gulp build/watch on command line).

I'm going to run the email build files from /resources/emails and then want to compile the distribution files into /resources/views/email and /public/email/images.

Some of the email templates will need to go directly into /resources/views/email but some will need to also sit in a sub-folder within this directory, e.g. /resources/views/email/order-confirmation.

How would I go about moving files into the main /emails directory and any I need to go into a sub-folder of the /emails directory?

Here's my [gulpfile.js][2], ignore the folder directories for now - I haven't set them up yet.